# AWS Personalize — eventType must be an associative array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

Documentation says that `eventType` must be a `string` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-personalize-events-2018-03-22.html#putevents

So I did:

```php
/* @var PersonalizeEventsClient $client */
$client->putEvents([
    'trackingId' => $trackingId,
    'sessionId' => $uniqueId,
    'userId' => '2',
    'eventList' => [
        'itemId' => '1',
        'eventType' => 'click',
        'sentAt' => (string) time(),
    ],
]);
```

But I receive next validation errors:

```
[eventList][eventType] must be an associative array. Found string(5) "click"
[eventList][sentAt] must be an associative array. Found string(10) "1611590718"
```

Any ideas how it should work? I've tried `json_encode`, `['eventType' => ['key' => 'click']]`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `eventList` must be an array of arrays. Problem solved:

```php
/* @var PersonalizeEventsClient $client */
$client->putEvents([
    'trackingId' => $trackingId,
    'sessionId' => $uniqueId,
    'userId' => '2',
    'eventList' => [
        [
            'itemId' => '1',
            'eventType' => 'click',
            'sentAt' => (string) time(),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Please mark this as answer to the question, so the question will be visible as answered :)